# Why i get added 5 hours instead 4 on daylight saving time when i use the add method and how can i resolve it?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I need to add 4 hours to my moment js date. So for that i am using

```
/* this timestamp is this date 27-03-2045 00:00 */
const someday = moment(2374178400000);
const addedFourHours = someday.add(4, 'hours');
```

on 27 March the DST is already passed and i get exactly 4 hours added and the end date in `addedFoursHours` is `Mon Mar 27 2045 04:00:00 GMT+0200`.

But when i try date when DST is happening for example 26 March on midnight

```
/* this timestamp is this date 26-03-2045 00:00  */ 
const someday = moment(2374095600000);
const addedFourHours = someday.add(4, 'hours');
```

then i get `Sun Mar 26 2045 05:00:00 GMT+0200`. In previous case i got 04:00 time when i added 4 hours after midnight. Why in DST time i get 05:00 time ?

How can i solve this ?

Comment: What is there to solve? When DST kicks in, the clock is moved from 02:00 to 03:00, so the hour between 02:00 and 03:00 is non-existing. Therefore if you count 4 hours from 00:00, you get to 05:00. The distance between 0:00 (before DST) and 05:00 (DST) really is 4 hours!

Comment: @trincot Firstly thank you for you comment, but I need when I add 4 hours i will get 04:00 instead 05:00 because because of DST. So even that DST has 3 hours then, i still need to get 04:00.

Comment: @trincot that is what I meant by solve it

Comment: It still represents the same moment in time that is actually 4 hours (240 Earth minutes) later. Not sure why you want to represent it as though DST didn't happen!

Comment: So what would you then want to happen if instead of 4 hours you would add 2 and a half hours? Note that "Sun Mar 26 2045 02:30:00 GMT+0200" is an invalid time. I don't understand what you want. Your variable is called `addedFourHours`, but you agree that in fact you want to only add 3 hours in that particular case. This code will be **very** confusing. If you want to really have the time part to be equal to `4:00`, then just set it like that: `someday.hours(4);` and don't have any suggestion in your code that you are adding 4 hours, because it is not true.

Comment: I'm sorry if I've insulted or upset you. I don't believe I presented an opinion. We are trying to understand what the actual problem is to help you. Explaining why you need to ignore the change in DST would be helpful to come up with proposed solution. I have come across requirements that are unreasonable and pushing back often requires a thought out reason and alternative way of acheiving the same goal. You're obviously trying to acheive something here and without knowing what that is won't help us to help you.

Comment: If you want to avoid all effects of timezones and daylight savings then work purely with UTC. The time you are seeing is only a representation of a specific moment in time and `Sun Mar 26 2045 05:00:00 GMT+0200` is exactly the same moment in time as `Sun Mar 26 2045 04:00:00 GMT+0100`.

Comment: @trincot i will always need to add 4 hours. So possible hours are 00:00, 04:00, 08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00.

Comment: @trincot So i will never have your case of adding 2 and half hours which does not exist.

Comment: @trincot well it is true, when I do not have DST then I am adding 4 hours. When I have DST then I still add 4 hours but I need to get that dynamically depending on the daylight saving time.

Comment: No, you're not always adding 4 hours. You're sometimes adding 3, 4 or 5 hours.

Comment: Ah, so you need to get consistent times of day irrespective of DST changes. That makes more sense.

Comment: @jabaa you are right, that depending on DST

Comment: @trincot— "Sun Mar 26 2045 02:30:00 GMT+0200" isn't an invalid date. I presume you're assuming it's in a DST changeover time, however there are many places with +2 as standard time that don't observe daylight saving (mostly southern hemisphere). Even for places that do, it's likely still a valid date, e.g. Damascus changes at midnight, Sofia changes at 3 am, etc.

Comment: OK, thanks for that detail, RobG, but for what the Asker has specified, the statement is valid (*"when DST is happening"*). We need to focus on one particular timezone and DST rule, or otherwise a time specification would not even be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add 3, 4 or 5 hours depending on the date, but you want to set specific values for the hours. Read the hour value, add 4 and set the value:

```js
const today = moment(2374178400000);
const four = moment(today).hours(today.hour() + 4);
const eight = moment(four).hours(four.hour() + 4);
const twelve = moment(eight).hours(eight.hour() + 4);
const sixteen = moment(twelve).hours(twelve.hour() + 4);
const twenty = moment(sixteen).hours(sixteen.hour() + 4);
const tomorrow = moment(twenty).hours(twenty.hour() + 4);

console.log(today);
console.log(four);
console.log(eight);
console.log(twelve);
console.log(sixteen);
console.log(twenty);
console.log(tomorrow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems to work. But why on this way moment.js is adding always 4 hours, but with addHours the DST was taken into consideration

Comment: @someusername12 That's not a comment. It's an answer. It doesn't add 4 hours. There's a big difference between adding 4 hours and setting the value. Setting the value ignores daylight saving.

Comment: Will thiswork for octomber also ? When we go one hour forward ?

Comment: @someusername12 Yes

Answer (score 1):

What you want is then actually not *adding* 4 hours, but finding the next time where the hours are a multiple of 4.

So, remove all suggestion from your code that you are adding four hours (cf. your variable name).

You can do this:

```js
const someday = moment(2374095600000);
console.log(someday.toString());
const hours = someday.hours();
someday.hours(hours + 4 - (hours % 4)); // Find next time that is multiple of 4.
console.log(someday.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems to work but that timestamp will only represent midnight in OP's timezone or a multiple of 4 hours in approximately a quarter of all timezones - I'm currently in UK I get initial time as `Sat Mar 25 2045 23:00:00 GMT+0000` and then `Sun Mar 26 2045 00:00:00 GMT+0000` so it only actually adds a single hour.

Comment: @phuzi what you mean by OP ?

Comment: @someusername12 OP is Original Poster - in this case that is yourself.

Comment: Sure, this assumes that the initial time is what you want it to be in your own timezone.